# Extending a prototype from an external library in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, module, typescript1.8, typescript-typings

I would like to extend the prototype of an external library in Typescript (1.8). The external library in my case is google.maps for which I have included the Typescript Definition file from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/google.maps.d.ts). Now I want to extend the prototype of the google.maps.LatLng by adding a distance function like so in a file "extensions.ts":

```
/// <reference path="./google.maps.d.ts" />
export {}

declare global {
    interface google.maps.LatLng {
        distanceTo(google.maps.LatLng): number;
    }
}

google.maps.LatLng.prototype.distanceTo = function(other) {
    return google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(this, other);
}
```

Then I want to use it:

```
import "./extensions.ts"

let p1 = new google.maps.LatLng(5, 5);
let p2 = new google.maps.LatLng(10, 10);

console.log(p1.distanceTo(p2))
```

However this code does not work with many errors :/
What is the correct way of solving that? Extending the global declarations like Array or String works that way as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38878403/add-a-function-to-a-prototype-globally-from-within-a-module/38880585#38880585).

Note: For the resulting file to work you also have to include the google maps javascript library:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&key=[your-key-here]&sensor=FALSE"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, it's just that you can't define an interface along with its namespace.
Should be:

```
declare global {
    module google.maps {
        interface LatLng {
            distanceTo(other: LatLng): number;
        }
    }
}
```

It compiles, but I haven't run it so I haven't checked for runtime problems.

Also, when you import do it without the `.ts` extension:

```
import "./extensions"
```

Comment: I did the runtime test and it works. Thanks a lot :)